# Why I can't cut there with the knife tool, I want to make a quad out of this n-gons

Tags: knife-tool

Why I can't cut there with the knife tool, I want to make a quad out of this n-gons

[image: no]

Comment: You question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

You can Cut Trough by pressing **Z** while knifing

> Allow the Cut tool to cut through to obscured faces, instead of only the visible ones.

or using Knife selection **Shift-K** (by default)

> Activates the knife with another set of options so only selected faces are cut and Cut through is on by default.

[Knife Tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife.html)

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be because the face is obstructed by other faces.

Try to hide all other faces by pressing Shift+H,

This will hide all faces, now you should be able to cut it easily, I suggest you to turn on vertex select mode to do so as you will see the vertecies more easily.

To unhide it all you press alt+H